# Вопрос по Union ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблицы `t1(id, client_name, date_begin, date_end)` и `t2(id,client_name, beneficiary, date_begin, date_end).` Как можно объединить через union all.

Comment: а в чем проблема - кол-во полей не совпадает?  поставьте в первом подзапросе в списке полей еще одно значение - `select id, client_name, '', date_begin...`

Comment: да в первом подзапросе 4 значение, а на втором подзапросе 5 значении и мне надо вытащить beneficiary и остальные поля.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте NULL-ы вместо недостающих колонок:

```sql
SELECT id, client_name, NULL as beneficiary, date_begin, date_end FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, client_name, beneficiary, date_begin, date_end FROM t2
```

Comment: В этом случаи в колонке beneficiary стоять только null т.е не показывает

Comment: @Zhandos что не показывает?

Comment: показывает(Beneficiary) но только null мне надо чтобы там были значении

Comment: @Zhandos для строк из первой таблицы будет null, для второй - реальные значения. проскрольте в конец результатов запроса - строки из t2 будут в самом низу.

Comment: хорошо,  спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Структура странная. Если клиент в обеих таблицах один и тот же (и id - ключ), то думаю, что вы не то заказали.
Мне представляется, что нужен примерно такой запрос:

```
    select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id), coalesce(t1.client_name,t2.client_name),beneficiary,
 coalesce(t1.date_begin,t2.date_begin),
    coalesce(t1.date_end,t2.date_end)
    from t1 full join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: t1 и t2 таблицы разных договоров и клиенты могут быть разными